# convert 12 word seed into 24 word seed

Tags: bitcoinj, android

I used bitcoinj library for wallet and it generates 12 word mnemonic seed.

But I made changes in it and created 24 word mnemonic seed.

But I need to convert old 12 word mnemonic seed into new 24 word mnemonic seed.

Please help me with this.

Comment: By changing the seed, you are changing the private keys.

Comment: Ok. So In BitcoinJ, how do i move all my private keys, addresses and balances to a new 24 word seed wallet from 12 words seed wallet without losing the ability to use the 24 words seed to restore the wallet in future?

Comment: You can't move the private keys but the bitcoins, just create another 24-word seed and make a normal transaction.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to export and import private key in bitcoinj?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible.

The mnemonic words are an encoding of the entropy used in the seed, essentially. A 12 word seed has less entropy than a 24 word one, so you cannot get 24 words out of it. Similarly, you cannot get a 24 word seed to turn into a 12 word one.

Your best bet is to generate a new 24 word seed and move funds over.

Comment: Ok. So In BitcoinJ, how do i move all my private keys, addresses and balances to a new 24 word seed wallet from 12 words seed wallet without losing the ability to use the 24 words seed to restore the wallet in future?

Comment: You don't move your keys, or addresses. You make a transaction from your old wallet to the new one, so that the coins are now controlled by the 24 word private keys

Comment: Can you please tell me how to export and import private key in bitcoinj?